# List all tags in current branch with JGit

Tags: java, git, jgit

How do I list all tags in the current branch with JGit?
I can list all tags easily

```
List<Ref> call = jGit.tagList().call();
for (Ref ref : call) {
    System.out.println("Tag: " + ref);
}
```

but how do I list only the ones that are in the current branch?

Comment: What do you exactly mean, when you say "tags in a branch"? A tag has no direct relationship to a branch. They are independend objecs that point to commit nodes.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Lets say I am on branch "A". I want to list all tags in chronological order that are on commits on this branch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all tags for a given branch, you need to walk the history commit by commit, starting from the head commit of the branch. For each commit in the history you then need to find all tags that point to this commit.

For example:

```java
git.commit().setMessage("tagged").call();
git.tag().setName("mytag").call();
git.commit().setMessage("untagged").call();

Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().call();
for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
  Map<ObjectId, String> namedCommits = git.nameRev().addPrefix("refs/tags/").add(commit).call();
  if (namedCommits.containsKey(commit.getId())) {
    System.out.println("tag " + namedCommits.get(commit.getId()) + " -> " + commit);
  }
}
```

The output will be something like this

```
tag mytag -> commit 92a85dcb2326caf08f4ad1ddb6132f92ee0b3e7c 1438794838 ----sp
```

where the commit is the *taggsd* one.

the `LogCommand` returns an iterator that starts with the the head commit of the current branch. The `NameRecCommand` called within the loop finds all tags that point to the given commit.

An optimized variant could use the `ListTagCommand` to once retrieve a list of all tags and then replace the `git.nameRev` code with code that looks up the current commit in the list of tags.

Comment: Unfortunately this code will only find the first tag for each commit, to find all of the tags you need to work through every tag using 
List<RevTag> list = git.tagList().call();
and compare their object reference with the sha1 of the commit your interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Tags in Git are not attached to a branch. Tags are global objects that are only attached to commits. That said, you would either

- need to check for each tag whether it's reachable from the branch's tip,
- or for each commit on a branch check whether it is a tag.

Answer (score 0):

I' ve not much experience with jGit. But theoretically you can perform a `git log --decorate=full` from your resp. branche. That schould be possible with the Porcelain API in jGit. This list you the commits from the branch top to the root (initial commit). In the log text of the tagged commits you can find a `(tag: refs/tags/<tagname>)` entry which you can parse with e.g. regular expressions.

Here is an example running on my command line.

```
$ git log  --decorate=full  |grep tag:
commit 1b1fac8c013c2e9fd629bb9f6387a0fc297190e3 (tag: refs/tags/ppk2)
commit f02f361bbffb838f7499ed63f0a9c0ae5565ff01 (tag: refs/tags/ppk1)
commit 24baea8bae11019941da86c79c612cedfa17a69f (tag: refs/tags/ppk4, tag: refs/tags/ppk3)
```

Hope that helps.

Perhaps there is a better way: but that's the only one I know.